# jquery each function to get input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I click add button then the same for will added next to the previous. I wan to get the values of input fields of each forms using `each()` function. I tried running below code.

```
$('.question-div').each(function(i) {
    //to get Degree field value.  
    console.log($(".question_Degree_0").val());                      
 });
```

The problem is like this way I only get two times the same value of the first form's Degree value. For example if I select 1 in first form, and if I add one more form, the second time also get the value '1' in Degree value though I select different value.. My question is what can I do so that I can get values of input fields using `each()` function?
Thank you.

Comment: Just try `console.log($(".question_Degree_0", this).val());`

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
$(".question_Degree_0", this).val()
```

inside your loop function.

or

```
$('.question-div .question_Degree_0').each(function(i) {
    console.log($(this).val());                        
});
```

Comment: @DharaParmar – I did not answer but did comment about this as I am not 100% sure about the markup and the context of the question.. If the person who answered _is_, he is free to answer.. ;)

Comment: @Rayon ok then +1 for him ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('input').each(function(i) {

     console.log($(this).val());//to get all the input value.                        
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the piece of code and the solution is as below

$('input').each(function(ele) { console.log($(this).val()); });